# Choose the highest value,regardless of when there is the same value multiple times

Tags: sql-server

I used the following code to retrieve the highest value from my countries 1 -5, but the code does render NULL when there are more than one country with the same value. How can I choose a) the highest value for country 1-5 and B) if some countries have the same value, then choose the first country (starting from 1) with that value.
This is the code I used:

```
    , Risk AS(
 SELECT *,
        (SELECT MAX(v)
        FROM (
            VALUES  (Redflag.[country1]), 
                    (Redflag.[country2]), 
                    (Redflag.[country3]), 
                    (Redflag.[country4]), 
                    (Redflag.[country5])) AS value(v)
        ) AS highest_risk  
FROM Redflag

)
```

This is what I got:

```
SELECT 1 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0 AS country4, 0 AS country5, NULL AS highest_risk
    UNION
   SELECT 2 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 2 AS country3, 0  AS country4, 0 AS country5,  2 AS highest_risk
    UNION
   SELECT 3 AS ID, 0  AS country1, 2  AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  2 AS highest_risk
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 0 AS country1,  0 AS country2, 0 AS country3, 0  AS country4,  5 AS country5,  5 AS highest_risk
    UNION
   SELECT 5 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 3 AS country3, 3 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  NULL AS highest_risk
    UNION
   SELECT 6 AS ID,0 AS country1,  0 AS country2, 0 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  NULL AS highest_risk
    UNION
    SELECT 7 AS ID, 0 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  0.5 AS highest_risk
    UNION
  SELECT 8 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5, NULL AS highest_risk
    UNION
  SELECT 9 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 4 AS country5,  4 AS highest_risk
```

I need it like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0 AS country4, 0 AS country5,  0.5 AS highest_risk
        UNION
       SELECT 2 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 2 AS country3, 0  AS country4, 0 AS country5,  2 AS highest_risk
        UNION
       SELECT 3 AS ID, 0  AS country1, 2  AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  2 AS highest_risk
        UNION
        SELECT 4 AS ID, 0 AS country1,  0 AS country2, 0 AS country3, 0  AS country4,  5 AS country5,  5 AS highest_risk
        UNION
       SELECT 5 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 3 AS country3, 3 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  3 AS highest_risk
        UNION
       SELECT 6 AS ID,0 AS country1,  0 AS country2, 0 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  0.5 AS highest_risk
        UNION
        SELECT 7 AS ID, 0 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  0.5 AS highest_risk
        UNION
      SELECT 8 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  0.5 AS highest_risk
        UNION
      SELECT 9 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 4 AS country5,  4 AS highest_risk
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Your query should do what you want. Probably, you are not running this exact query against this exact sample data.

Comment: It is part of a CTE, should it be more close to the data source?

Comment: [Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bda577d0530267f3dd7c6b1f76c9dc2c). Results are those that you want with your existing query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.  The 'max_risk' column contains a) the highest value for country 1-5.   The 'min_country' column contains b) if some countries have the same value, then it chooses the first country (starting from 1) with that value.

Data

```
drop table if exists #redflag;
go
with data as (
SELECT 1 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0 AS country4, 0 AS country5, NULL AS highest_risk
    UNION
   SELECT 2 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 2 AS country3, 0  AS country4, 0 AS country5,  2 AS highest_risk
    UNION
   SELECT 3 AS ID, 0  AS country1, 2  AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  2 AS highest_risk
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 0 AS country1,  0 AS country2, 0 AS country3, 0  AS country4,  5 AS country5,  5 AS highest_risk
    UNION
   SELECT 5 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 3 AS country3, 3 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  NULL AS highest_risk
    UNION
   SELECT 6 AS ID,0 AS country1,  0 AS country2, 0 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  NULL AS highest_risk
    UNION
    SELECT 7 AS ID, 0 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5,  0.5 AS highest_risk
    UNION
  SELECT 8 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 0.5 AS country5, NULL AS highest_risk
    UNION
  SELECT 9 AS ID, 0.5 AS country1,  0.5 AS country2, 0.5 AS country3, 0.5 AS country4, 4 AS country5,  4 AS highest_risk
)
select id, country1, country2, country3, country4, country5
into #redflag
from data;
```

Query

```
with country_cte(id, country1, country2, country3, country4, country5, v_n, v_v, rn) as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by v.v desc, v.n) rn
    from
      #redflag r
      cross apply
     (values  (1, r.[country1]), (2, r.[country2]), 
              (3, r.[country3]), (4, r.[country4]), 
              (5, r.[country5])) AS v(n, v))
select id, country1, country2, country3, country4, country5, v_n min_country, v_v max_risk
from country_cte 
where rn=1;
```

Output

```
id  country1    country2    country3    country4    country5    min_country max_risk
1   0.5         0.0         0.5         0.0         0.0         1           0.5
2   0.5         0.5         2.0         0.0         0.0         3           2.0
3   0.0         2.0         0.5         0.5         0.5         2           2.0
4   0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         5.0         5           5.0
5   0.5         0.5         3.0         3.0         0.5         3           3.0
6   0.0         0.0         0.0         0.5         0.5         4           0.5
7   0.0         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         2           0.5
8   0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         1           0.5
9   0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         4.0         5           4.0
```